# What is meant by $(dS \times \nabla)\times \vec F?$ Confusion about question

Tags: notation, vector-analysis, cross-product

I want to answer the following question:
$$\vec\nabla \times (\vec a \times \vec F) = \vec a(\vec \nabla \cdot \vec F)-(\vec a \cdot \vec\nabla)\vec F.$$
'By applying Stokes' theorem to the above identity, show that
$$\int_C d\vec l \times \vec F = \int_S (d\vec S\times \vec \nabla)\times \vec F$$
for any closed curve $C$ that bounds a surface $S$.'

I have no idea what is meant by $d\vec S \times \vec \nabla$ or how to approach this question; I understand Stokes' theorem and what is meant by $(\vec a \cdot \vec \nabla)\vec F$, but I don't think you are allowed to use standard properties of the cross product (anticommutative etc.) to rearrange the RHS.

$\vec a$ and $\vec F$ are generic vector fields.

Comment: $a$ and $F$ are generic vector fields ?

Comment: yes, I will clarify that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, $d\vec{l}$ is the (vectorial)-length element along the curve and $d \vec S$ the area element where the vector points orthogonal to the element.

If you apply Stokes to the first equation, you obtain $$\int_{C}d\vec{l}\cdot(\vec{a}\times \vec{F}) = \int_S d\vec S \cdot\left[\vec a(\vec \nabla \cdot \vec F)-(\vec a \cdot \vec\nabla)\vec F\right].$$

Next, we employ the [triple product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)
$$  d\vec{l}\cdot(\vec{a}\times \vec{F}) = -\vec{a}\cdot(d\vec{l}\times \vec{F}),$$
the relation
$$d\vec S \cdot\left[\vec a(\vec \nabla \cdot \vec F)-(\vec a \cdot \vec\nabla)\vec F\right]= \vec a \cdot\left[ d\vec S (\vec \nabla \cdot \vec F) - \sum_{j=1}^3 dS_j \vec{\nabla} F_j\right] ,$$
and [Lagrange's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) (were we have to make sure that the derivative acts only on $\vec{F}$)
$$(d\vec{S}\times \vec{\nabla})\times \vec{F}  = -d\vec S (\vec\nabla\cdot \vec F) + \sum_{j=1}^3 dS_j \vec\nabla F_j.$$

Putting everything together, we can conclude that
$$\vec a \cdot \int_C d\vec l \times \vec F = \vec a \cdot \int_S (d\vec S \times \vec\nabla)\times \vec F.$$
As $\vec a $ is arbitrary, we have shown the result as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand why we can use Lagrange's formula with $\vec \nabla$; it is not commutative or associative so can't be treated like a vector, surely?

Comment: @RobNo: I made sure not to commute (dS is on the very left, $\nabla$ in the middle, and F on the right) that is what the comment in the bracket was all about. The rest is simple algebra and essentially given by equation (4) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Product). It should not take you too much trouble to prove it yourself (given you know how to prove Lagrange's formula in the conventional case).